# ERROR! Fabric Docker image version of 1.1.0 does not match the versions supported by the test network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, docker-image

I have downloaded the latest fabric version which is 2.2.0 using the following command from hyperledger documentation website

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

But when it comes to run a test network using its network.sh file using the following command as directed by the hyperledger documentation website

```
./network.sh up
```

I get the following error

```
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'cryptogen'

2020-08-26 05:55:40.852 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
LOCAL_VERSION=2.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
===============================================
ERROR! Fabric Docker image version of 1.1.0 does not match the versions supported by the test network.
```

and the screenshot is following:
[image]

I want docker image version which is 1.1.0 to be same or align with local fabric version which is 2.2.0. I saw previous stackoverflow questions but they asked to downgrade local fabric version from 2.2.0  to 1.1.0 and that solved the problem but I want to work on newest hyperledger fabric version which is 2.2.0. So I want to know how to upgrade docker image version from 1.1.0 to 2.2.0 so that it can work with local fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `network.sh --help` command to check how to use various options available with it.
2. Below is the snippet from `./network.sh --help`

   `-i <imagetag> - the tag to be used to launch the network (defaults to "latest")`
3. Use `network.sh up -i 2.2` to run `docker` on `v2.2` images.